# Use jQuery to append multiple variables to query string

Tags: jquery

I'm currently passing a variable to query string with select drop downs and jQuery using this:

```
$("#filter_1").change(function(e) {
  window.location.href = '?filter_1=' + $(this).val()
});
$("#filter_2").change(function(e) {
  window.location.href = '?filter_2=' + $(this).val()
});
```

This is working great. However, if you select `filter_2` after having already passed the `filter_1` variable, `filter_1` gets overwritten in the query string. What I need now is a way to append the `filter_1` and `filter_2` and vice-a-versa. Any ideas?

Comment: Changing the queryparam reloads the page. Are you also setting the value of the selects based on the params when the page loads?

Comment: To add to Kevins response. Every time page loads your select would loose the selected previously value. You need to handle it by passing the selection to server and restoring it upon page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you create a function which parses the query string for you and returns `key=value` of the requested key if it exists or just an empty string if it doesn't.

```
$("#filter_1").change(function(e) {
   window.location.href = '?filter_1=' + $(this).val() + 
      querystring('filter_2', '&');
});
$("#filter_2").change(function(e) {
   window.location.href = '?filter_2=' + $(this).val() + 
      querystring('filter_1', '&');
});


function querystring(name, prefix)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return '';
  else
    return (prefix||'')+name+'='+ decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Function originates from: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: This was really close! I had to edit your code slightly, but it was 99% what I needed. Thank you!

I had to add the "&" separator to connect to the two variables: 'window.location.href = '?filter_1=' + $(this).val() + '&' + querystring('filter_2');'

Comment: I would totally upvote but it looks like I don't have enough "reputation" yet.